# Banco de dados Access ficando pesado após executar consulta via VBA

Tags: sql, vba, microsoft-access

Seguinte, eu tenho um banco de dados `Access` com uma tabela chamada `tblDados`.

Essa tabela contém 19 campos iniciais.

Eu faço a importação de um arquivo CSV `que` contém 1 milhão de registros, até ai tudo bem, salvo e fecho o banco de dados **sem compactar e reparar**, o mesmo fica com 135 MB.

O problema é quando executo uma consulta via `VBA`. Essa consulta percorre toda a `tblDados` e limpa os dados de uma determinada coluna. Ela está funcionando corretamente, mas quando salvo e fecho o banco de dados **sem compactar e reparar**, o mesmo fica com `274 MB` e, se eu rodar a consulta novamente ele aumenta o banco de dados para `1,6 GB`.

Eu fiz alguns testes habilitando a opção de **compactar e reparar** ao fechar o **access**, ele reduz e muito o arquivo. Porém, eu necessito executar várias consultas com essa via VBA com o banco aberto e depois de terminar os processos posso excluir a tabela inteira e compactar ao fechar.

Há algo de errado com minha consulta que está consumindo muitos recursos do banco de dados atual e pesando dessa maneira?

O que posso fazer para executar a consulta e diminuir/liberar recursos para o banco de dados?

Código `VBA` da consulta:

```
Public Sub removeDadosObsoletos()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblDados.DATA_ULTIMA_MOVIMENTACAO FROM tblDados;")
    Dim lQtd As Long    //variável que recebe a quantidade total de registros
    //conta o número de registros
    rs.MoveLast
    lQtd = rs.RecordCount

    //variável que irá contar os registros
    Dim lContador As Long
    lContador = 0
    //loop que irá percorrer a tabela
    rs.MoveFirst    //vai para o primeiro registro

    Do While Not rs.EOF

        rs!DATA_ULTIMA_MOVIMENTACAO = ""

        lContador = lContador + 1 //acrescenta 1 na quantidade

        rs.MoveNext //proximo registro

    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

    MsgBox "Registros obsoletos removidos com sucesso!", vbInformation, "Otimização dos Dados..."

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Cara, uma sugestão seria vc criar uma consulta gera tabela para outro banco access.